# DllImport Not Working

Tags: c#, .net, dllimport

I'm trying to write a WPF application which uses a function defined in C++. The C++ application is compiled as a DLL.

What I'm doing is using the DllImport attribute to import the function and use it. This works fine on my machine but when I attempt to run my WPF application on another machine it gives a "cannot find the DLL" error.

An excerpt of my C# (WPF) code:

```
[DllImport("Dll.dll")]
public static extern int MyFunc();

public MainWindow()
{
  InitializeComponent();
  MessageBox.Show("Starting");
  try
  {
    MessageBox.Show(MyFunc().ToString());
  }
  catch (Exception exc)
  {
    while (exc != null)
    {
      MessageBox.Show(exc.Message);
      exc = exc.InnerException;
    }
}
```

My C++ code:

```
extern "C" __declspec(dllexport) int MyFunc() {
  return 3;
}
```

Can anyone see where my error might be?

Thanks in advance for your help!

EDIT: It would appear that the issue is that the dependency "MSVCR100D" isn't present. My understanding is that this is a file in the VC++ Redistributable package which I have installed by to no avail.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Your DLL might depend on other DLLs that are not installed on the other machine. You can check the dependencies with [Dependency Walker](http://www.dependencywalker.com/).

Typical missing dependencies are the Visual Studio C/C++ Runtime libraries. If they are missing, just google for it. Microsoft offers redistributable packages for them.

Comment: Thanks for that. I'll try both of those.

Comment: I profiled the application with Dependency Walker and it didn't show the DLL I'm using in its analysis (thus, in addition to this presumably being a problem in itself, I can't find the DLL's dependencies)

Comment: Analyze the C++ DLL with Dependency Walker, not the C# one. And if MSVCR100D.dll is missing, then you need to switch from a debug build to a release build because MSVCR100D.dll (D for debug) may not be distributed and is not part of the redestributable package.

Comment: The issue appears to be that I was producing a DEBUG release and thus the DEBUG dependencies weren't available on the client machine (grabbing them from my computer and putting them in the application's root directory corroborates this). Presumably a RELEASE build will remedy this so I'll mark this as the answer. Thanks heaps!

Answer (score 0):

Is the dll registered on the other machine too ? Try setting the Build ACtion to Content and Copy to Output folder to always for the dll file